# Cannot solve java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I'm writing a program to calculate the Hamming code, and I receive an array out of bounds exception. The issue seems to be with this method:

```
static int[] computeParityBits(int[] inWord, int[] parityBits) {
for (int i=0, m=2; m < inWord.length; i++) {
    m = (int) Math.pow(m, i);
    parityBits[i] = processPower(m, inWord);
}
return parityBits;
```

The integer m does not change it's value when using the `Math.pow` function on it. I've tried different things but I can't seem to make it work properly. The method is supposed to go through all powers of 2 as long as their value is lower than `int[] inWord.length`. After this it should assign `parityBits[i]` the value returned by the method `processPower()`.

The exception received:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>       at hamming_code.HammingCoder.computeParityBits(HammingCoder.java:34)
>       at hamming_code.HammingCoder.computeHammingCode(HammingCoder.java:27)
>       at hamming_code.HammingCoder.main(HammingCoder.java:61)

A larger section of the code:

```
    static int[] computeHammingCode(int[] inWord, int codeLength) {
    int[] parityBits = new int[codeLength - inWord.length];
    parityBits = computeParityBits(inWord, parityBits);
    return parityBits;
}

static int[] computeParityBits(int[] inWord, int[] parityBits) {
    for (int i=0, m=2; m < inWord.length; i++) {
        m = (int) Math.pow(m, i);
        parityBits[i] = processPower(m, inWord);
    }
    return parityBits;
}

static int processPower(int m, int[] inWord) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inWord.length; i++){
        for (int n = 0; n < m; n++) {
            counter = counter + inWord[i];
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else 
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: m is less than inWord when i=5, but the parityBits array is only 4 items long. That's throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message indicates that it fails for `i = 5`, but your loop is conditioned on the value of `m`, so something is wrong with your loop.

Printing the value of `i` and `m` for each iteration up to `i = 5` will show you the error:

```
for (int i=0, m=2; i <= 5; i++) {
    m = (int) Math.pow(m, i);
    System.out.println(i + ": " + m);
}
```

**OUTPUT** ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/TfIGDa))

```
0: 1
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1
```

As you can see, `m` is always `1`.

That is because first iteration calculates:

```
i=0,m=2: 2⁰ = 1
i=1,m=1: 1¹ = 1
i=2,m=1: 1² = 1
i=3,m=1: 1³ = 1
i=4,m=1: 1⁴ = 1
i=5,m=1: 1⁵ = 1
```

Debugging your code should have easily shown you this, faster than getting answer here.

Comment: Thanks, I see where the mistake is now. Just starting to learn how to code, so thank you for your help and patience!

Answer (score -1):

I see nothing to prevent i from exceeding `codeLength - inWord.length`.  That would account for the exception.

Answer (score -1):

You get error because  on fist iteration you have `Math.pow(m, 0);` and it equals to 1. Then `m` always will be 1, because power of 1 always 1. So `i` is incremented, but `m` not. But exit loop conditional `m < inWord.length`.